# Images show in Safari, but not in Firefox, Chrome etc

Tags: image, firefox, google-chrome, safari, show

I have stumbled into this very weird problem today. I was messing around with some images on my website (Primarily in Safari), when i noticed, that neither Firefox, Chrome or Opera would show any of the images. Then i tried to link to the image with an absolute path like seen in the attached image, but it still wont work.[image: Safari vs. Firefox]

As seen in the screenshot, the top browser (Chrome), ain't showing the image, but the bottom browser (Safari) is.

Any thoughts of what could be wrong?

**EDIT**
Okay, so I've figured this out (Sorry for not checking this before I did the post).

But I was sure that it was something with my paths in my CSS files, but it wasn't. - Then it must have to be saving an PNG as Non-interlaced or Interlaced, but i wasn't that either.
Then instead of saving the images as 8-bit PNG, I tried saving it as 24-bit PNG, and this did the trick.

Once again, sorry for posting this, too soon!

Answer (score 0):

When I open your image (http://onlinevind.dk/cms/library/images/mod_login/login-btn-bg.png) with GIMP it tells me that it has a color profile embeded ("Generic RGB Profile"). Some other programs I tried even refused to open the file with the error message "Not a PNG file".

Maybe you should save it without a color profile. It is also a good idea to use a program like pngcrush to reduce the file size of images used in web pages.